# Unity.Check if object is coliding with another in a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game (similar to Subway Surfers), and I have a floor made of many small cubes. And I want to make my game do something when the player stops colliding with the floor. But when I use OnTriggerExit (Collider other) I never know if the player stops colliding the floor or just moves from one piece of the floor to another:

```
OnTriggerExit (Collider other){

    if (other.tag == "floor") {

        if(/*Object isn't coliding with any other object with the tag "floor" (Or simply isn't coliding with the other piece of the floor) */){
            //Do something
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: You're using `OnTrigger...` instad of `OnCollision...`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the needs of the game. Since you named Subway Surfer, I would go with the z-coordinate of the player.

I would add the `heightFromGround` field to the player class (calculated as the difference on the z-axis between the player and the platform underneath).

Then, if `heightFromGround` is higher than a threshold, you know the player is jumping.
This also allows you to control the Animation of the character based on it's height from the ground (so he can prepare to land) and transition to the running state.

To have different platforms at different heights, you need to know the platform currently underneath the player at runtime.

This is just an approach to avoid collision checking.

If you don't need that level of control on Animations and prefer to keep using collisions, you can simply add a field `int touchingPlatforms = 1;` and add 1 to it OnCollisionEnter, subtract 1 from it OnCollisionExit. The player is jumping if `touchingPlatforms` is 0.